# Confused by Continuity Equation

Tags: computational-mathematics, differential

I thought I was aware of it. My question is about the derivative of time.
Sometimes it is the total derivative

[image]

and sometimes it is partial, we can ignore the $\phi$ here

[image]

Does mass change with time or position?

Comment: Please use MathJax to format the math instead of posting pictures. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In these equations, $\rho$ is the density.  It should not be surprising that density can depend on time and position.

When we integrate over the entire system, we do get the mass.  Having integrated over the whole system, there is no possibility of position dependence.  However, there can easily be time dependence if mass is being added to or removed from the modeled system.  (Typical examples: chemical reactions produce gasses which escape the system, nuclear interactions convert mass to energy or vice versa, evaporation from a [free boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_boundary_problem) is being modeled, a bullet is fired into a semi-elastic medium, et al.)

When we integrate over a modeling cell, position dependence becomes possible.  For instance evaporation can occur from a cell meeting the free boundary, but not from an interior cell.

Comment: Thank you, integral the control volume, is it the entire system?

Comment: @majordoctor : A [control volume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_volume) is not the entire system.  If the system under study is in steady state, then the mass entering a control volume equals the mass leaving a control volume, so the contained mass should not vary with time (but may vary between the control volumes, hence with position).  If the system is not in steady state, the mass can change with time as well.  The control volume lint discusses the substantive derivative, which is the subject of the other Answer here.

Comment: "Having integrated over the whole system, there is no possibility of position dependence." I think I know this is right, but I cannot convince myself, would you please explain more?

Comment: @majordoctor : When you integrate over a variable, that variable ceases to be in the result.  If you integrate over all of time, $t$, there is no "$t$" in the result.  If you integrate over all of $x$, $y$, and $z$, none of $x$, $y$, or $z$ appear in the result.  If you integrate over a control volume, the contributions to the integrand in the CV are lumped together so you lose resolution inside the CV, but each CV is distinguishable from CVs at other positions, so there is still some chunky position information among the CVs.

Comment: So after I integrate it under CV, I want to derivate this respect to t, I need partial right?

Comment: @majordoctor : As described in the prior comment -- if your control volume is the entire computation volume, there is no variation of $x$, $y$, or $z$ with respect to $t$, so the total derivative would be the partial derivative.  If you have a control volume smaller than the computation volume and the control volume moves, then there is variation of $x$, $y$, and/or $z$ with respect to $t$, so the total derivative is not the partial derivative.

Answer (score 0):

The total derivative is made of two pieces: the partial and the convective. You are following an individual particle in your fluid. It’s density can change because of local compression/rarefaction or because of the particle moving to a different location. If you write the continuity eqn in integral terms the time derivative should be total since it only depends on time once you fix your control volume. When you localize the equation you obtain
$$
\frac{d\rho}{dt}+\rho {\rm div}v=0
$$
With total time derivative which equals
$$
\frac{\partial\rho}{dt}+v\cdot\nabla\rho
$$
When you replace the total time derivative by this expression you can put together the second and third terms which amounts to taking the density inside the divergence.

Comment: Thank you GReyes, if I want to integrate a changing configuration of a continuum body, it  should be a partial derivative out of the integral right?

Comment: Please read Eric Tower's comment above. Once you integrate in space, you obtain a quantity that only depends on time, so the derivative is not partial, it is just $d/dt$.